# Comment Posted Immediately On Paste in iOS App

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, ios-app

When adding a comment in the iOS app, if you paste a link to another question, the comment is automatically posted *immediately*, and with the last character chopped off to boot.

I've seen the truncation error in other ways, so that's probably a separate bug, but I've yet to reliably reproduce it so as such haven't posted it. I've reliably reproduced the paste post pest though.

Comment: Thanks for the report, I'm checking this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an issue where pasting content with newline characters would cause the form to be submitted, because that's also how we detect if the "Send" button on the keyboard is tapped.

This will be fixed in 0.1.19.

Comment: @ShadowWizard my mistake, I meant 0.1.19. See update above.